# IIS Redirect Old Site to new site

Tags: iis, iis-6

In IIS we have a website. We are turning this website off. We have redirected all the pages to another server using the redirect. So any hits to example.com will be displayed as example2.com.

We wish to turn the old server off. So the redirect will no longer work. I know I need to change the DNS of example.com to go to the IP address of example2.com.

Is it possible to get the IIS site to handle example.com and server any requests to that to the default page of example2.com?

Or is it better to create a new site on the server for example.com and get that to redirect to example2.com like the site on the original sever that has been switched off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new site.  Edit the properties of the site in IIS for example2.com and add a host header redirection for example.com.

1. On the Web Site tab of the web site's properties page click the Advanced button next to the IP Address drop-down
2. Click Add unter Multiple Identities for this Web Site
3. Enter 80 for your TCP port (assuming your site is running on port 80)
4. Enter example.com in the Host Header value, click
5. Click Ok until you're back to IIS manager.

What this does is tells IIS to route any request that comes in with example.com as the value for the `Host:` HTTP request header to the web site for example2.com.

Comment: What would be differnt if on IIS7? Is it just change the bindings?

Comment: Right, just an additional binding for the site for IIS7.